# Is there a way to serialize this class?

Tags: java, jackson

```
@JsonSerialize(using = TestDefSerializer.class)
public class TestDef{
  private List<TestStep> steps = new LinkedList<>();
  private String name;
} //Getter and Setters are defined
```

I can't seem to figure out a way after this

```
public class TestDefSerializer extends StdSerializer<TestDef> {
    public TestDefSerializer(Class<TestDef> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    public TestDefSerializer(){
        this(TestDef.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(TestDef testDefinition, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        // What should go here in order to serialize List<TestStep> ???
    }
}
```

TestStep has a couple of fields namely responseDef (which has path , method) , requestDef (mathcing , status)  etc. I wish to skip a couple of fields in responseDef and requestDef

Comment: Any reason why you need a custom JSON serializer for your class?

Comment: You want to exclude the field `name` from serialization ?

Comment: TestStep has other fields RequestDef and ResponseDef , i wish to exclude couple of fields from there

Comment: Just use `@JsonIgnore`, don't write a custom serializer for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are chances you don't even need to implement a
`TestDefSerializer` at all , because Jackson is probably
smart enough to pick up enough information from the getters
of your `TestDef` class.
Just omit the line

```
@JsonSerialize(using = TestDefSerializer.class)
```

on your `TestDef` class and check if this will already
produce the JSON output you want.

But anyway, here is how to proceed if you want to
implement your own `TestDefSerializer`.
Look up the the [API docu of `JsonGenerator`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator.html).
It describes all the `write...` methods available
for writing the JSON pieces.
For example, there is method `writeStartArray()` for writing a `[`,
and `writeEndArray()` for writing a `]`.
So in your `TestDefSerializer` class you may end up
with a `serialize` method looking like this:

```
@Override
public void serialize(TestDef testDefinition, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
    jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();         // write {
    
    jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("name");     // write "name":
    jsonGenerator.writeString(testDefinition.getName());
    
    jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("steps");    // write "steps":
    jsonGenerator.writeStartArray();          // write [
    for (TestStep testStep : testDefinition.getSteps()) {
        jsonGenerator.writeObject(testStep);  // this will invoke the serializer for TestStep
    }
    jsonGenerator.writeEndArray();            // write ]
    
    jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();           // write }
}
```